# No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

This is a strange error when I ran React Native (0.63.2) app on Android 8.1 emulator with

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Here is the full warning message:

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Opening developer menu...
```

Tried `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` but didn't help. The emulator was working fine. What can go wrong here?

Comment: Run `./gradlew clean` under `/android` solved the problem.

Comment: Awesome ran into this and was trying everything!

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Answer targets only those visitors, who are facing this issue after successfully running once on device

```
npx react-native run-android
//once its installed on device next time just do
npx react-native start
```

installs app at your device on first run. I was facing same issue only when I tried `npx react-native run-android` second time.

So I used `npx react-native start` then

I just opened my latest app installed by last run and its working and showing  me the updates as well

Comment: For me the metro bundler is not starting and the hot reload is not working.